# Android: How to find if an activity is invoked by a service

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I am using an Activity to start a service.
In the service, I send notifications based on locationListener.
When a notification is send the user clicks on the notification and the MainActivity is called.

I would like to show an Alert box when the MainActivity is evoked by the Service.

Here is the code in the Service class

```
public class NotificationService extends Service implements LocationListener{
     private NotificationManager mNM;
     private Notification notification;
     private int NOTIFICATION = 123;
.
.
.
        private void showNotification(String msg) {
            long[] pattern = { 0, 1000, 1000 };//pattern for the vibration
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            CharSequence text ="EasyTransit notification";
            notification = new Notification(R.drawable.arrow, text, System.currentTimeMillis());
            Intent contentIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
           // PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
            contentIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "EastTransit.Prepare to get off", msg, PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getBaseContext(), 0, contentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;     
            //notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrator.vibrate(pattern , -1);
             try {
                    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
                    r.play();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

..
```

I would also like to know how to send the string msg to the Activity called by the service

How can I achieve these?